# Load image from Core Data = UITableView stuck

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

This is my first post - I'm new to iOS developing ;)

I'm working on an app where the user can store some things like a title, a text, an image in core data and it is shown in a tableview.

I read many tutorials and try to puzzle things together - everything is working good so far, but when I scroll a "little faster" in the tableview, it kinda get stuck. I googled for hours, what I think I know, is that the reload of the cells each time, probably cause of the image, makes it stuck. I read about async tasks, grand central dispatch and so on, tried to use some example code but I can't get it to work. So some tips from the pros would be great :)

This is where I fill my cells, and I guess I have to do this somehow async/reusable, but how?

```
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSManagedObject *object = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = [object valueForKey:@"title"];

    NSDate *date = [object valueForKey:@"date"];
    NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [format setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy"]; 
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [format stringFromDate:date];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[object valueForKey:@"image"]];
    cell.imageView.image = image;
}
```

Comment: Probably you shouldn't store images in core data, but strings that represent the path to the file. Anyway, your issue here with slowing down is likely because the images are too large. Create thumbnails of your images and display those in your cell.

Comment: Thx for the answer. i want to store the images permanently, so that the images are not gone when user quits the app. Maybe I get it wrong, but is it not a good idea then to store the images in core data like all the rest? Also if the user selects a cell, he can see the larger image then in a detailview and even zoom in and so on, so i guess thumbnails is not the solution, or can i use the thumbnails just for the tableview? if so, how? thx

Comment: It's not a good idea to store the image into CoreData, no - generally you would store them into the Documents directory and save the filepath into CoreData. Yes just use the thumbnails for the UITableViewCell, and the full size image for the rest

Comment: Thx, I see. As I said, I am still noob, so I hope I understand right. I Once saved recorded sounfiles in the "app-directory" and added a time-string to the URL to not overwrite the file. can i do it similar to that?    self.recordedSoundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSTemporaryDirectory()         stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@.wav", self.todaysDateString]]; is that NSTemproyDirectory that Documents Dir that you mean?

Comment: Only use NSTemporaryDirectory if you don't care to persist the images across application launches. As the name implies the files stored there will not stick around forever.